# How to match two lists of tuples?

Tags: list, matching

It's easy enough when the elements are primitive values, and a match is for identity.  Unfortunately, I've got lists of distance and direction, and I want to see if anything in one list "obscures" (is in the same direction and closer than) anything in the other and just retain the ones in the first list that are not obscured by anything in the second.  I'm happy to sort the lists, but the matching and list management is getting complicated.  Direction is a pair of integers (dx and dy) and only exact matches are interesting.
The tuples in both lists are of the form (dx, dy, distance)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem correctly, but wouldn't this help:

1. Put the list items into buckets by their direction.
2. Sort each bucket by distance, so that the least distant item is always the first one.
3. Take only the first item from each bucket.